# C# BackgroundWorker Wait Until Ends

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I'm working in a projects that needs to be done with a thread.

I have a background worker that does the job. What I want to accomplish is when I hit `Button3`, my background worker will restart. I have already tried to wait for background worker to finish with `Backgroundworker1.IsBusy` in a while, but this never ends. When I hit `Button3`, I get the error

> This BackgroundWorker is currently busy and cannot run multiple tasks concurrently

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
    }

    private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        int x = 0, y = 0, result;

        while (true)
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                x++;
                y++;
                result = x + y;
                this.label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => this.label1.Text =     result.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

}//public partial class Form1 : Form
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listen for the completed event, and then restart the worker there -

```
private bool restartOnCancel = false;

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    restartOnCancel = true;
    backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled == true) && restartOnCancel)
    {
        restartOnCancel = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: you only need the restartOnCancel if you plan on cancelling work without restarting the job. If cancel means always restarting the job, you can just remove all the restartOnCancel stuff.

Comment: True - I assumed from the example that since button1 starts, button2 cancels, and button3 restarts, that it's necessary - but if those were just for testing and you really just want to restart every time, you can remove the restartOnCancel parts.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I just added             if(!backgroundWorker1.IsBusy)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); 
            }
in button3 so that i can start the work from there too.
Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, that would also work if it ended quick enough, or if it had already completed to begin with. A combination of both methods might offer the best results.

Answer (score 0):

The background worker hasn't completed before the RunWorkerAsync call.  You could hook up a method to the RunWorkerCompleted event and call RunWorkerAsync in there if button3 was pushed.